# Wordpress plugins sub menu not and delete button not showing

Tags: wordpress

WordPress plugins submenu not and delete button not showing. Please see the below  image in my plugins dashboard:

[image: dashboard plugins delete option not showing]

Comment: Can you please show what you have tried? Also please see our quick [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: Are you using Wordpress Multisite?

Comment: no i am not use Multi site

Comment: Perhaps the file/folder permissions are set such that your web server user may not delete files from the disk?

Comment: Did you upgraded your wp setup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into your wp-config.php for `define( 'DISALLOW_FILE_MODS', true );`. If there is anything written in that remove it.